# VSTS (TFVC): customising builds and hosting NuGet packages

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-artifacts

We are still using an in-house TFS 2012 server but I'm now looking at moving to VSTS. I have a couple of questions though:

Years ago I customised our build process template to perform a number of additional tasks, and I was wondering if VSTS builds can be customised in a similar way, specifically to do what we currently do:

- Run StyleCop
- Change the version number in every AssemblyInfo.cs file in the solution prior to building (the major and minor numbers are specified in the build definition).
- Run a batch file at the end of the build which runs an InnoSetup script to create a "setup.exe" file (the batch filename is againspecified in the build definition).

(The first two are (I think) DLLs that came from the now defunct [tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com) site).

Second question: we currently have an in-house NuGet repository. Am I right in saying I could host this on VSTS instead? And will that be accessible both to VSTS builds and our dev team?

Answer (score 1):

The newer build system is fully extensible. You can simply add "Command Line", "Batch File", or "PowerShell" tasks to run whatever commands you'd like during your build process. Any customizations you made to your XAML build process templates will have to be ported manually, but it's entirely possible that someone has created free extensions that are available to install from the VSTS marketplace that replicate the behavior you're seeking.

VSTS supports package management feeds. It's an extension and requires additional licensing, but the simple answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: Can such command lines and batch files be run at different points during a build (e.g. after "getting" but before building), or are you restricted to running them once the build has finished?

Comment: At any point. I'd strongly recommend looking at the documentation for the build system, because all of this is very thoroughly explained there.